# My Chrome extension does not persist when chrome closes

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, persist

My Chrome extension does not persist when chrome closes, although I did not specifically request it to stop, and the chrome settings are set to persist background tasks.

condition:

1. chrome=>settings=>advance settings=>system:
   "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" IS CHECKED!
2. My extension's manifest includes:

   "background": {
     "page": "background.html",
     "persistent": true
   },

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest file should also contain the ["background" permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html#background):

```
{
    ...
    "permissions": [
        "background"
    ],
    ....
}
```

Comment: Don't you just love it when you get an answer that's both simple and works :)
Thank you friend